# How to change the preferred content size when UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate is added?

Tags: ios, swift

Wanted to get the callback when the popover is dismissed by dragging down in iOS 13. For the reason `presentationController?.delegate` is added `(UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate)`,
However once this delegate is added and tried to present using `addVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet` , the property `preferredContentSize` is not working? Without conforming to the delegate callbacks are not triggered but the `preferredContentSize` works perfect. wanted both, anything have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you should implement function
`adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle`
in order to use wanted presentation style. In my case it returns `.formSheet` style to manipulate `preferredConentSize` value. I hope it helps!